# Closing My Own Question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I recently posted the following ['trick question'](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/35879/an-amazing-palindrome) which met a lot of mixed reception (twelve up votes and twelve down votes)

Now I don't want to delete the question, due to the time people have spent on it anyway, and in favour of the accepted answer.

I have edited the question multiple times in favour in the accepted answer, however users are still proposing other answers that are not in the spirit of the puzzle. I consider this to be quite a waste of time, since they are no longer *good* answers, but rather just the reiteration of other answers.

Anyway, this brings me to a broader point:

Is there a reason why I cannot close my own question, and rather can only vote and have to wait?

Comment: Ty clicking on "flag", clicking on "in need of moderator intervention", and explaining what you want.

Comment: Hmm. I see that I have the independent privilege of VTC my own question, but it doesn't necessarily do anything. I don't want to flag it, because that would indicate that there was something *wrong* with the puzzle, which there isn't. I have flagged it anyway though, on your advice - hopefully it will bring a moderator's attention to it.

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that

Comment: Ah okay, seems like I'm going to have to just leave it.

Comment: Flagging isn't indicating something is *wrong*, it is merely inviting moderators in to take "action" whatever it is.